# Function 'hasattr()' doesn't work as I expected in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, hasattr

Function 'hasattr()' doesn't work as I expected in Python

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import os
import sys

results=[{'data': {}, 'name': 'site1'}, {'data': {u'Brazil': '5/1', u'Panama': '2000/1'}, 'name': 'site2'}]

print results[1]
if hasattr(results[1]['data'], u'Brazil'):
    print 'has'
else:
    print 'hasn\'t'
```

When I run it, it gives me the output: `hasn't`.
I don't understand how to check the property if it exists.
I tried to remove `u` before `Brazil` but it doesn't work.
How to solve it?

Comment: This is not an attribute, you can check membership of a key in a dictionary/set with `'Brazil' in results[1]['data']`.

Comment: Maybe the title should be "What is hasattr used for?" because it works exactly as expected, although your expectations may have been different.

Comment: @SethMMorton: edited

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hasattr(..)` checks if an object has an *attribute* with the given name. But like the conditions says correctly, there is no `somedict.Brazil`.

You can check membership of a *key* in a dictionary with `in`, like:

```
if u'Brazil' in results[1]['data']:
    print 'has'
else:
    print 'hasn\'t'
```

Note that this only checks if there is a *key* in the dictionary that is equal to the given key (`u'Brazil'`), it does not check the values, for values, you can for instance use `'5/1' in results[1]['data'].values()`. Note that searching for *keys* is usually done in *O(1)*, whereas searching for values will run in *O(n)*.

Answer (score 3):

`hasattr` operates on *attributes*, not on *dictionary keys* - if you can access it with dot notation (as in `data.Brazil`) then `hasattr` will return `True`, otherwise it will return `False`- and in this case it will return `False`.

Use `in` instead:

```
if u'Brazil' in results[1]['data']:
```